# JQuery Validate fails when Boolean value is quoted by json_encode

Tags: jquery-validate, boolean, quotes, json

I found a problem from using json_encode to create a string to pass as metadata to JQuery Validate (bassistance version): it encloses Booleans in quotes which JQuery Validate does not like.  Here is my input to json_encode:

```
Array
(
    [messages] => Array
    (
        [required] => notEmpty
    )

    [required] => true
)
```

The output is

```
{"messages":{"required":"notEmpty"},"required":"true"}
```

but JQuery Validate just ignores it.  However if I hack my code and change it to this:

```
{"messages":{"required":"notEmpty"},"required":true}
```

the validation works correctly (note the missing double quotes around true).

I didn't see any options for json_encode related to Booleans, but are there any options that would get the string in the format required by Validate (other than writing my own json_encode)?